# Tempus Dominus v6.0 and IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm attempting to use the new [Tempus Dominus 6](https://getdatepicker.com/) datepicker, which is great in Chrome but doesn't like IE11 because of the presence of `class` syntax.

Is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) the only/best way of handling the incompatibility?

Our software is required to support IE11 in legacy environments - the organisations we provide for have thousands of machines which are only very slowly moving to modern browsers.

In this case, the latest version of Tempus Dominus removes reliance on momentjs and jquery, which would be of benefit to us if practicable.

Comment: _"Is Babel the only/best way of handling the incompatibility?"_ - No. Best option is to get rid of the unsupported and soon to be uninstalled IE.

Comment: As per updated question, we have a requirement to support IE, so removing IE isn't an option.

Comment: How many times are you going to make the same comment over and over again here?

Comment: As many times as it takes to get people like yourself to acknowledge that supporting IE11 (unfortunately) is something that some of us can't change, so our questions regarding supporting it are entirely valid and justified.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to support IE compatibility with this plugin, then I think using Babel is a good choice. The main reason in IE11 is that it cannot parse `es6` syntax (such as arrow function), so a transpiler like Babel is needed to make it work.

> Is Babel the only/best way of handling the incompatibility?

As far as I know, Babel works with most front-end frameworks to support site compatibility within IE 11, I think this is because of the advantages of Babel itself that makes it so popular.

Comment: Thank you - I asked because I was having problems getting the converted Babel file to work, but bizarrely my original comment to Andreas above has been deleted, and the question has also been closed as opinion based when it's not really. Perhaps I shoudn't have used the word "best" in my sentence.